# Why does a Bidirectional iperf request freezes on the server to client side?

Tags: linux, iperf

To diagnose the difference in network trafic between two locations and our main server center, I'm using iperf to log the traffic rate with the following command:

```
iperf -c <server ip> -F 500MB_Test_File.zip -n 500M -y C
```

After noting disparities between upload and download rate, I wanted to use the `-d` option and stumbled on a weird behaviour: although the transfer went through in the client to server direction, in the other direction it freezed and didn't seem to tiemout. Here is a test I did which shows that it isn't connected to the fact I'm using a file as source for the data transfer:

```
$ iperf -c <server IP> -d -i 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to <server ip>, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  153 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  5] local <local ip> port 35144 connected with <server ip> port 5001
[  4] local <local ip> port 5001 connected with <server ip> port 39967
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]  0.0- 1.0 sec  9.75 MBytes  81.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  10.7 MBytes  89.3 Mbits/sec
[  5]  1.0- 2.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.2 Mbits/sec
[  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.3 Mbits/sec
[  5]  2.0- 3.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
[  5]  3.0- 4.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
[  5]  4.0- 5.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  4.0- 5.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
[  5]  5.0- 6.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  5.0- 6.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
[  5]  6.0- 7.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.2 Mbits/sec
[  4]  6.0- 7.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
[  5]  7.0- 8.0 sec  11.2 MBytes  94.4 Mbits/sec
[  4]  7.0- 8.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
[  5]  8.0- 9.0 sec  11.1 MBytes  93.3 Mbits/sec
[  5]  9.0-10.0 sec  11.1 MBytes  93.3 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec   109 MBytes  91.4 Mbits/sec
^C^C
```

I'm using iperf 2.0.5. Both clients and the server are linux machines, server being virtual.

**EDIT**

After following [MariusMatutiae](https://superuser.com/users/255732/mariusmatutiae)'s suggestion I started the iperf server on the client machine and then tried to make the bidirectional request from the VM and here is what I got:

```
[host@centos ~]$ iperf -c <client_id> -d -i 1
bind failed: Address already in use
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to <client_id>, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 19.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local <server_id> port 40175 connected with <client_id> port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  11.6 MBytes  97.5 Mbits/sec
[  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  9.50 MBytes  79.7 Mbits/sec
[  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  10.6 MBytes  89.1 Mbits/sec
[  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  4.0- 5.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  5.0- 6.0 sec  10.9 MBytes  91.2 Mbits/sec
[  4]  6.0- 7.0 sec  11.0 MBytes  92.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  7.0- 8.0 sec  10.8 MBytes  90.2 Mbits/sec
[  4]  8.0- 9.0 sec  8.38 MBytes  70.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]  9.0-10.0 sec  9.75 MBytes  81.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   105 MBytes  87.8 Mbits/sec
[host@centos ~]$
```

I thought, great, the command stops from itself, but I only get the results in one direction. That is until I looked into the machine where I started the iPerf server this time and saw this:

```
$ iperf -s
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local <client_ip> port 5001 connected with <server_ip> port 40179
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to <server_ip>, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  6] local <client_ip> port 36243 connected with <server_ip> port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  6]  0.0-10.0 sec  45.4 MBytes  38.0 Mbits/sec
[  4]  0.0-10.2 sec  64.2 MBytes  52.8 Mbits/sec
```

So it got me thinking that maybe I need to start a server as daemon on both side of the connection for the bidirectional command to work and indeed, I got a similar results, only outputing the performance in one side of the transaction, but as such I don't have any way to get the performance data in the other side: I did start the iperf daemon with `-D > iperflog` but the log doesn't seem to be populated...

Is it suppose to be like that, that a iperf is supposed to be running in both machine for a bidirectional request to go through? Does the `bind failed: Address already in use` message i get when I start an iperf client and a server is running on both side a clue as where the issue might lie? I get the feeling that what I am doing is not supposed to be the standard procedure...

Comment: What happens if you use the host, instead of the VM guest, as the other end of the connection?

Comment: You mean using the VM as iperf client and the former client as server? I'll have to give it a try, I'll get back to you.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae tried it and added some information

Comment: The error message `bind failed: Address already in use` means you cannot run both a client and a server on the same pc. The correct way to use is to start a server on one machine, and a client on the other machine with the `-d` option (no `-d` option for the server). You said one server is virtual: is the other pc the host of the virtual server?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: the hosts are on different locations, as we want to test the traffic between some of your sites and our main server center. But as I mentioned in my last edit, the issue seem to be with the server started as a daemon, which was not intuitive in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected and Marius confirmed client and server can't run on the same machine. So I waited for an opportune time to kill the daemon so it wouldn't run concurrently to the client, started the server only with `-s` on the host (which is on a totally other location, as Marius asked), started the bidirectional request on the VM and the request went through (Thought of the moment: "What the...").

And then it hit me, I get the issue only if the server is started as daemon.

I confirmed my hypothesis by testing both with server as a daemon and not a daemon, as well as swapping the role of the machines.

**Summary: If you want to use bidirectional requests, don't start the server as a daemon.**

Comment: I realized that instead of trying to make the server work as a daemon, most users in my situation would probably be content to have a working server and run it without the `-D`option, so I remove the content of the question and made it the answer.